# ionic framework - unable to prevent ion-toggle from toggling

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using ion-toggle in my app . when user clicks(checks) on the ion-toggle , i have written ionChange hook on the ion-toogle . In this hook ,due to application logic , i am giving prompt to the user saying ion-toggle can not be set .

## using event.preventDefault to prevent ion-toggle to toggle

### component html

```
<ion-content padding>
     <ion-slides pager="true">
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let giftSlide of giftsAllMatrix" >
    <ion-row *ngFor="let giftRecord of giftSlide">
      <ion-col *ngFor="let giftCol of giftRecord" col-6>
        <img src="./assets/{{giftCol.giftImage}}" >
          <p> gift code :  {{ giftCol.giftCode }} </p>
          <ion-item>
         <ion-toggle   #giftSelect (ionChange)="onGiftSelect(giftCol.giftCode, giftCol.pointsRequired ,giftCol.giftImage,giftSelect.checked,giftSelect,$event)" checked="false"></ion-toggle>
          </ion-item> 
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
```

### component hook - onGiftSelect

```
onGiftSelect( giftSelCode : string , 
           pointsRequired : number ,
           giftImage : string , 
            selected : boolean 
           ,giftSelect : any,
           event : Event)
      {
         console.log("inside onGiftSelect "+giftSelCode);
         console.log("inside onGiftSelect  points required "+pointsRequired);
         console.log(" selected "+selected );
         console.log(" this.giftSelectedFlg "+this.giftSelectedFlg );
         let navigate = true;
         // if ion-toggle is true then only navigate 
         // when toggle is from 'selected' to 'deselected' do not 
         if ( selected === true)
         {
            if ( this.giftSelectedFlg  === false )
            {
                this.giftSelectedFlg = true;
            } 
            else
            {

                if(isProdSetup() === true)
                {
                    this.toast.show( "Select one gift at time ", '3000', 'center').subscribe
                    ( toast => 
                    {
                        console.log(toast);
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                     let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                     title: 'Gift selection',
                     subTitle: 'Multiple gift selection disallowed',
                     buttons: ['Dismiss']
                     });
                     alert.present();
                }
              navigate = false;
              event.preventDefault();
        }
         if ( navigate)
        {
           // Pass the control to giftSelect page 
           this.navCtrl.push("Giftselect",
              {
                 giftCode : giftSelCode ,
                 pointsRequired : pointsRequired ,
                 giftImage : giftImage
              });
         }

    }
```

## using viewchild

### using nativeElement

this code also does not work . Can anybody help me to get right way to prevent ion-toggle component prevent toggling in ionChange event.

```
 export class Giftfactory {
      giftsAllMatrix : GiftCatalogueEntry[][][];
      gifts : Array<any> ;
      totalPoints : number = 0;
      error : string;
      giftSelectedFlg : boolean = false;
      giftChoice : any;
      //giftSelect :  any; //template variable.
     @ViewChild ('giftSelect') gtSel ;

onGiftSelect( giftSelCode : string , 
           pointsRequired : number ,
           giftImage : string , 
            selected : boolean 
           ,giftSelect : any,
           event : Event)
    {
    ...
        // trying to uncheck ion-toggle - does not work
        this.gtSel.nativeElement.checked = false;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure of how your app should work, but just an idea... instead of waiting for the user to toggle it to make that validation, would it be possible to make that validation in all the toggles when the page is loaded, and show the ones that can't be toggled as disabled? Another solution would be to bind the toggle with `[(ngModel)]` and set it back to false when the validation runs and the toggle should not be activated.

Comment: @sebaferreras i tried with [(ngModel)]. However here the problem is that i have 4 ion-toggle components on the same page and once i bind using [(ngModel)] , all ion-toggle elements gets bounded to single model variable . I do not know how i can use [(ngModel)] with  array /Map

Answer (score 1):

Adding a `@click` listener (in addition to the `@ionChange` listener) and running `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` inside the click handler did the trick for me! It stopped the toggle from being toggled, and allowed me to set its value programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

## ion-toggle tag

```
<ion-toggle  #giftSelect (ionChange)="onGiftSelect(giftCol.giftCode, giftCol.pointsRequired ,giftCol.giftImage,giftSelect.checked,giftSelect,$event)" checked="false"></ion-toggle>
```

## toggle event handler

Use template reference variable giftSelect to access ion-toggle. giftSelect is passed to the event handler. use checked property to set toggle off.

```
 onGiftSelect( giftSelCode : string , 
               pointsRequired : number ,
               giftImage : string , 
                selected : boolean 
               ,giftSelect : any)
   {
      //make toggle off ,depending on the application logic.
      giftSelect.checked = false;

   }
```